# Adroid Blockchain wallet ver 4.0.12 recovery

Tags: blockchain, wallet-recovery, android

Just repaired my old Android phone, with Blockchain wallet version 4.0.12. It is asking for either the four digit PIN or the password, which I have both forgotten.

Is there any way to recover this now seven years old wallet?

Comment: Do you have your recovery phrase

Comment: Not sure if recovery phrase was even asked for at the time of opening this wallet, back in 2014.

Answer (score 1):

> **Is there any way to recover this now seven years old wallet?**

No.

This is because you probably ignored any advice to

- keep somewhere safe a separate written note of your recovery phrase (seed phrase, backup phrase) or private key.
- Make regular backups of important data on your computers (including on your phones)
- Practise recovery from those notes and backups.

It is also because Android phones protected by PINs and passwords take measures to prevent thieves accessing your private data. As an inevitable side-effect, those measures also prevent you accessing that data if you forget your phone's PIN and Password and didn't make a written note kept somewhere safe.

---

> **I can open the phone, that PIN code I can remember. However, I do not remember the PIN code for the Blockchain wallet.**

If you have access to the phone, and have some idea of what your wallet password might have been like, there are tools that may help you to sucessfully guess the password. These tools may take a very long time and not succeed.

For example https://github.com/gurnec/btcrecover says

> Bitcoin wallet password recovery support for:
> [...]
>
> - Blockchain.info
>
> [...]

Comment: The screen of this phone was broken for years and I just managed to change it.I can open the phone, that PIN code I can remember. However, I do not remember the PIN code for the Blockchain wallet.

Comment: The [Blockchain wallet](https://www.blockchain.com/wallet) is described as *"You’re the custodian, you have control."*. That means if you forget the PIN etc, and didnt make backups or write down the recovery phrase, you can no longer use that money.